# Async pipe where no element

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an `Observable` that I'm using like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories$ | async">
    <div class="box__subtitle">{{ category.title }}</div>
    <div class="box__content">
        <div class="question" *ngFor="let question of category.questions">
            <div class="question__title" [innerHTML]="question.title"></div>
            <div class="question__answer" [innerHTML]="question.answer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

However, I'd like to be able to display a message when the `Observable` returns no element. I did it by doing this in the `ngOnInit`:

```
this.categories$.subscribe(result => this.empty = result.length === 0);
```

And then adding

```
<div class="box__content" *ngIf="empty" style="text-align:center;">
    <i class="fa fa-frown-o" style="font-size:1.2rem;margin-right:5px;"></i> Random error message
</div>
```

In my template. It works but I'm wondering if there is not a better way to do so. Something like:

```
<div class="box__content" *ngIf="categories$.empty()" style="text-align:center;">
    <i class="fa fa-frown-o" style="font-size:1.2rem;margin-right:5px;"></i> Aucune question ne correspond à votre recherche
</div>
```

Comment: in the first line, did you mean `let category of categories$ | async`?

Comment: Yep, sorry, copy/paste issue. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
*ngIf="!(categories$ | async) || (categories$ | async).length == 0"
```

Comment: Edited, this should work for empty arrays as well as simple nulls/undefines